# How do we get the vector $\vec{r}$ in vector calculus?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

I can't figure this out.  The vector $\vec{r}$ is expressed in terms of $\vec{r1}$ and $\vec{r2}$.  How is this done mathematically? The question I am speaking of is shown below?

I've tried expressing d1 as its unit vector times d1, and doing some general geometrical manipulations with algebra, but no matter what I do, I cannot express r in terms of r1 and r2.

The answer seems to pull it out of nowhere, and I just can't figure it out

[image]

Comment: Looks like weighted average to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\overrightarrow{OQ}=\overrightarrow{OQ_1}+\overrightarrow{Q_1Q}$$
$$=\underline{r}_1+\frac{d_1}{d_1+d_2}(\underline{r}_2-\underline{r}_1)$$
$$\Rightarrow\overrightarrow{OQ}=\frac{\underline{r}_1d_2+\underline{r}_2d_1}{d_1+d_2}$$